# Escaping of slashes in Apache Ant

Tags: apache, ant, properties-file

Using Apache Ant, I want my propertyfile to output

```
blurb=test\n\
```

But with this, the \n\ will escape the slashes during build

```
<propertyfile file="about.properties">
    <entry key="blurb" value="test\n\"/>
</propertyfile>
```

So the output will be

```
blurb=test\\n\\
```

which is incoorect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can echo the literal string `\n` with the `propertyfile` task by using the built-in `line.separator` property. However, this will produce different output such as `\r\n` if you run the script on a non-Unix system.

```
    <propertyfile file="about.properties">
        <entry key="blurb" value="test${line.separator}" />
    </propertyfile>
```

Result:

```
#Thu, 07 Mar 2019 10:33:16 -0800

blurb=test\n
```

Regarding the trailing backslash, this isn't possible because the `propertyfile` task doesn't just blindly echo strings into a file; it actively maintains a property file and applies automatic formatting. A trailing escape character just gets formatted into nothing, since nothing comes after it for it to escape.

For example, if you manually created the following properties file:

```
blurb=test\n\
```

...And then ran the following code:

```
    <propertyfile file="buildNumber.properties">
        <entry key="anotherProperty" value="anotherValue" />
    </propertyfile>
```

You'd end up with this:

```
#Thu, 07 Mar 2019 10:42:43 -0800

blurb=test\n
anotherProperty=anotherValue
```

The backslash is removed despite the fact that the script didn't even do anything to the `blurb` property.

If you really, *really* want to write `blurb=test\n\` into your file for some reason, you can do so with the `replaceregexp` task (or just the `replace` task, if you know exactly what the existing value will be):

```
    <replaceregexp
        file="about.properties"
        match="blurb=.*"
        replace="blurb=test\\\\n\\\"
    />
```

Comment: You forgot the fact that a trailing single backslash is interpreted as a "continuation" character by `java.util.Properties.read()` : this allows having the value of a property on multiple lines. Here it disappeas after applying the Ant script because `Properties.store()` always writes the values on a single line.

Comment: @Lolo That's just formatting for human readability; the property value itself does not contain backslashes. As far as Ant is concerned, the trailing backslash is meaningless.